# Automate creation of new SVG based on path

Tags: svg

Problem: I need to create SVGs of each of the 50 united states from this SVG: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_US_Map_(states_only).svg

I have inkscape, but extracting each of the images, then resizing the canvas to fit the shape and saving a new file 50 times over on a buggy, open-source program seems tedious.

Is there an automation process via Automator or npm that I can create a new svg file based on the path data?

Comment: Personal advertisement: I have published a node module exactly for that task: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-icon-toolbox

Comment: wow! this looks great. Can you walk me through how I would export each individual state shape from that US map in the answers?

Comment: Raise an issue on the project.